# how to send apns push notifications custom messages with url or image in php

Tags: php, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I was able to send ipad push notifications successfully to an iPad App with the simple text message using the PHP framework ApplePushNotificationPayload by tinyurl.com. I read that there is a possibility to send custom messages like image or button etc.

Can anyone suggest how I can send url or image along with notification message with php apns push notifications?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see an option to add icon url in the library that I am using. May I know which library are you referring to?

Comment: I figured out that we cannot send image as an iPad notification, instead we can display an image from the application bundle while sending a notification. But it would be good if apple supports dynamic images in notification

Answer (score 0):

With apnsphp, it doesn't have URL option to send a push notification. I think it doesn't customize

Comment: ok.. If I can't send a url in the message, Is there an option to send image along with message as part of notification?

Comment: I figured out that we cannot send image as an iPad notification, instead we can display an image from the application bundle while sending a notification. But it would be good if apple supports dynamic images in notification.